# post back dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, autopostback

[on this site](http://iranfairco.com/example/postback.aspx) 
when dropdownlist contains only one item, when clicked it doesn't cause a post back

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("a");

        DropDownList2.Items.Add("a");
        DropDownList2.Items.Add("b");

    }
}


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(DropDownList1.Text);//does not work ????????????
}
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(DropDownList2.Text);

}
```

[on this site](http://iranfairco.com/example/postback.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged will never trigger because you only have 1 item in DropDownList1, thus index will never be changed.

**Updated**

What you can do is add a null value to the dropdownlist1, like so

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Choose option" Selected="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="a" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` won't trigger because the selected index is already `a`.
A list of `DropDownList Events` can be found here [DropDownList Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_events.aspx). The event `DataBound` should trigger, where you can do `Response.Write(DropDownList1.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add a new item at index 0 which says 'Select' and when user changes selection it will causes a post back...

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add("SELECT");
DropDownList1.Items.Add("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

`asp:DropDownList` with `AutoPostBack="true"` renders as html `select` tag that has client side `onchange` event and a java-script function automatically generated to handle this client side `onchange` event.

i.e. if you have:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

the rendered page source looks like:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DropDownList1\',\'\')', 0)" id="DropDownList1">
```

as you see in order to `postback` the client side `onchange` event has to be triggered. clientside `onchange` will occur only if html `select` tag has two or more `option`s select-able.

I see solutions are already posted, just thought would be nice to explain it in details.

In two words there have to be more than one `asp:ListItem` for the `asp:DropDownList` control.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a similar thing. Code below did it for me. Make sure it is the first code in your `SelectedIndexChanged` method.

```
//fixes error when postback 
    if (DropDownList.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
       DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```